# Find BPM iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, audio-processing

I'm looking a way to find the BPM of a song stored in the iphone library wuthout playing it. I'm not experienced on that, anyone can confirm me that it's possible?

Comment: Anyone can confirm me that the avasset property related to the bpm is not set in by default in the iPod library?

Answer (score 3):

I have never used it, but here's an open source c++ beat detection library you could try:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/beatdetektor/

Answer (score 0):

Possibly.  The AVFoundation framework and AVAssetReader can be used to convert library music into raw waveform data.  You could try writing a DSP spectral envelope follower and do an autocorrelation on the envelopes to estimate the BPM.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's running into this problem today... I made a github repo which shows how you can grab bpm of a local audio file.

https://github.com/yaizudamashii/BPMDetection-iOS